# Why doesn't this statement update the data in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL. Whats wrong with this code? It doesn't update data.

```
"INSERT INTO highscores (name, score, maila, ip)" . "VALUES ('$name', '$score', '$maila', '$ip')" .
"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score;" . "UPDATE highscores SET (if score>'$score') {score=$score} WHERE name=$name"
```

**This works:**

```
"INSERT INTO highscores (name, score, maila, ip) ".
     "VALUES ('$name', '$score', '$maila', '$ip') " . "
on duplicate key update score = greatest(score, $score)"
```

Thanks to **binaryLV**:
[MSQL: How to overwrite entry only if new one is higher? else create new entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253382/msql-how-to-overwrite-entry-only-if-new-one-higher-else-create-new-entry/6253419#6253419)

Comment: Please post the full line of code (preferably with context) as well as the error you receive.

Comment: You are showing us the **middle** (but not the start or end) of a PHP statement there. That is less than helpful. (It does appear to be inviting a visit from [little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) though.)

Comment: Please show your final, generated SQL query, not the PHP original

Comment: No, when can i check error message?

Comment: Ok i will delete it and post new qwustion, sry

Comment: First off, what's with the random double quotes and period in the middle of your SQL statement? You're definitely missing a decent chunk of code: `INSERT INTO highscores (name, score, maila, ip)" . "VALUES ('$name', '$score', '$maila', '$ip')`

Comment: @Verteru, no ... edit this question to make it clearer.

Comment: `md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5($score)))))))))))))` 13times md5? never seen something like that!

Comment: @JON: This is working OK, second part do not update data.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy - I thought the same thing. Maybe trying to make sure it's *really* super MD5'd? Like all the way.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you must also specify what to update, that is, in PHP, the right query would be:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO highscores (name, score, maila, ip) ".
     "VALUES ('$name', '$score', '$maila', '$ip') ".
     "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score='$score'";
```

Comment: He wants to update it only if the score was grater then the current value. I don't know mSQL syntax for this. The rest is up to you :) EDIT: so its MySQL... score = IF(score>$score, $score, score)