# MSQL: How to overwrite entry only if new one is higher? else create new entry

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I have table named "highscore" like this:

nameQL   scoreQL
piotr    50

And flash game with NAME and SCORE exported to PHP with this names.

**How to make this in PHP file:**

- IF (NAME exists in database (nameQL)
  AND SCORE> this.name.scoreQL){Raplace scoreQL
  with SCORE WHERE nameQL=NAME}
- IF (NAME doesn't exists){Create
  new row with NAME and SCORE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `insert .. on duplicate key update ...` statement. Something like this:

```
insert into highscore set
    name = :name,
    score = :new_score
on duplicate key update
    score = greatest(score, :new_score)
```

`name` column should be indexed as `unique`.

Test script:

```
create table player (
    name varchar(32) primary key,
    score int not null default 0
);

-- create new players
insert into player set name = 'foo', score = 100
    on duplicate key update score = greatest(score, 100);
insert into player set name = 'bar', score = 100
    on duplicate key update score = greatest(score, 100);
insert into player set name = 'baz', score = 100
    on duplicate key update score = greatest(score, 100);

-- update score of existing player
insert into player set name = 'bar', score = 200
    on duplicate key update score = greatest(score, 200);
```

Output of `select * from player`:

```
+------+-------+
| name | score |
+------+-------+
| bar  |   200 |
| baz  |   100 |
| foo  |   100 |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: I want to update score if it's higher than max score by this user not by everyone.

Comment: That's what it does. It operates on single-row level. Though, I mistakenly used `max()` where `greatest()` should have been used.